# Json.Net and Monotouch Compiling

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, json.net

Has anyone compiled the Json.Net Library Successfully? I found an old dll I used in the past that seems to work, but if I attempt to use a new one it fails. I attempted to build it myself, but the System.Dynamic doesn't not exist in Monotouch and is Require for the Portable Lib to compile. Does anyone have an idea of how to get around System.Dynamic in Json.Net or Another way to bulid the dll?

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look around the Xamarin components library and there other people that have reported the same problem that you are stating.

Now I dont have a test enviroment to try this out but in the JSON.Net library downloaded from http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/113546 there is a folder under \Bin\Portable40 or \Bin\Portable a compiled version that should compile with a portable class library.

It definitely compiles with a PCL but not sure about MonoTouch. It would be great to hear if this worked for you.

Comment: I tried to compile it just for monotouch that did not work I didn't think about trying to compile it as a PCL, I don't really know if Xamarin has this option. I'll try, but as it requires the System.Dynamic runtime I don't know if it will work. Xamarin has a compiled libaray that works, but it is not up to date. If decompiled it has also does not contain any reference to System.Dynamic. I'm not sure if they changed it or if its a legacy version. I'll try making a PCL on XS and in VS to see if either would work.

[edit: I made sure to try Portable40 and Portable]

Answer (score 0):

I'd checkout this thread...

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1801/which-newtonsoft-json

... seems to be a discussion about the same problem.  They suggest downloading and compiling the source, or if you're really game you can download the dll attached to a comment in the thread

Comment: I tried that that Json.Net requires the System.Dynamic which is not apart of the Xamarin runtimes or libraries as such it will not compile

[edit: I see the https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json seem to work from what people said, but it still has a runtime that Xamarin does not include and I can't get it to compile I'll try to see if I can figure out what the work around was.]

Comment: That is what I'm currently using but I want to use Json.Net in Lib that I am building this would require that the user import Json.Net and my DLL

Comment: So the Json.NET dll works?  But you want to include the Json.NET code in your own assembly?  Why? To get around some code access security issue?

Comment: I'm afraid that the lack of a reliable Json.NET DLL in monotouch will cause my library to function incorrectly. Mostly fear of unreliability due to what I have experienced in trying to find a dll.